# exact and case insensitive match for a multi word token in a string python

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I have a list which contains and a single and multi-word token.

```
brand_list = ['ibm','microsoft','abby softwate', 'tata computer services']
```

I need to search any of these words present in a title string. I am able to find a single word. But for a multi-word token, my code fails. 
Here is my code. Please help me out. Here is my solution.

```
import string
def check_firm(test_title):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    title = test_title.translate(translator)
    if any(one_word.lower() in title.lower().split(' ') for one_word in brand_list):

        status_code_value = 0
        print("OEM word found")
    else:
        status_code_value = 1
        print("OEM word not found")

    print("current value of status code ------------>", status_code_value)
```

Comment: `title.lower().split(' ')` looks fishyy

Comment: It is. It tokenizes the string base on space. When I search for multi-letter word, it fails. Here is the test string - " tata computer services , not much of success"

Comment: See if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this**:

```
if any(one_word.lower() in title.lower().split(' ') for one_word in brand_list):
```

**to this**:

```
if title.lower() in brand_list:
```

**Hence**:

```
import string
brand_list = ['ibm','Microsoft','abby softwate', 'TATA computer services']
brand_list = [x.lower() for x in brand_list] # ['ibm', 'microsoft', 'abby softwate', 
                                             #  'tata computer services']

def check_firm(test_title):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    title = test_title.translate(translator)

    if title.lower() in brand_list:
        status_code_value = 0
        print("OEM word found")
    else:
        status_code_value = 1
        print("OEM word not found")

    print("current value of status code ------------>", status_code_value)

check_firm('iBM')
check_firm('Tata Computer SERVICES')
check_firm('Khan trading Co.')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
OEM word not found
current value of status code ------------> 1
```

> Note: I converted all the elements in the list to `lower()` using:

```
 brand_list = [x.lower() for x in brand_list]
```

This will ensure the comparison is made correctly.

**EDIT**:

**OP**: *but my input tile is title string. for example "Tata Computer SERVICES made a profit of x dollars". In that case, how can we find the string?*

In such case, I would opt for splitting the string before passing to the function:

```
inp_st1 = 'iBM'
inp_st2 = 'Tata Computer SERVICES made a profit of x dollars'
inp_st3 = 'Khan trading Co.'

check_firm(inp_st1)
check_firm(" ".join(inp_st2.split()[:3])) # Tata Computer SERVICES
check_firm(inp_st3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my input tile is title string. for example "Tata Computer SERVICES made a profit of x dollars". In that case, how can we find the string?

Comment: @RohitHaritash you should split the input string before passing to the funciton. and pass only the desired string.

Comment: I was about to comment on that, seems that should be stated in the answer so as not to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to find two words because of this code:

```
title.lower().split(' ')
```

Say your title is **tata computer services**, when you carry out that code you'll en dup with:

```
["tata", "computer", "services"]
```

Then in your **for loop** you will only search for each singular word, essentially you've broken the title into something you can't match.

Writing the **for loop** in human words:

```
any(one_word.lower() in title.lower().split(' ') for one_word in brand_list)
```

*If any of the words in brand_list can be found in the array ["tata", "computer", "services"], then that's true.*

As you can see, no words from **brand_list** can match, since the word is actually composed of three words and spaces "tata computer services".

**To carry out what you are looking for:**

Change this:

```
if any(one_word.lower() in title.lower().split(' ') for one_word in brand_list):
```

to:

```
if any(one_word.lower() in title.lower() for one_word in brand_list):
```

That way you are looking for each word from **brand_list** inside the title. Your code would look like this:

```
brand_list = ['ibm','microsoft','abby softwate', 'tata computer services']

 import string
def check_firm(test_title):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    title = test_title.translate(translator)
    if any(one_word.lower() in title.lower() for one_word in brand_list):
        status_code_value = 0
        print("OEM word found")
    else:
        status_code_value = 1
        print("OEM word not found")

    print("current value of status code ------------>", status_code_value)

check_firm("ibm")
check_firm("abby software")
check_firm("abby softwate apple")
```

With the following output:

```
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
OEM word not found
current value of status code ------------> 1
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
```

**EDIT**

**OP**: *I tried your solution. The issue is it will also hold true for input like "tata computer servicessssssssss". Any idea to overcome this issue. Thanks*

In the comments it was highlighted that this code would let pass a title like **tat computer servicesss**. To avoid this then I suggest regex expressions, such that:

```
brand_list = ['ibm','microsoft','abby softwate', 'tata computer services']

import string
import re
def check_firm(test_title):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    title = test_title.translate(translator)
    if any(re.search(r'\b' + one_word.lower() + r'\b', title) for one_word in brand_list):
        status_code_value = 0
        print("OEM word found")
    else:
        status_code_value = 1
        print("OEM word not found")

    print("current value of status code ------------>", status_code_value)

check_firm("tata computer services")  
check_firm("tata computer servicessssss")  
check_firm("tata computer services something else")
```

**Output**

```
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
OEM word not found
current value of status code ------------> 1
OEM word found
current value of status code ------------> 0
```

The part that is of interest is:

```
any(re.search(r'\b' + one_word.lower() + r'\b', title) for one_word in brand_list):
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The issue is it will also hold true for input like "tata computer servicessssssssss". Any idea to overcome this issue. Thanks

Comment: @RohitHaritash the code in this answer overcomes that solution, if it works be sure to comment or upvote so others can quickly find the answer as well.